# i lost the connection with my vps server

Tags: ubuntu

i am using vps running by ubuntu.
i lost the connection with my vps server by making a fatal error by changing the network interfaces setting located in /etc/network/interfaces
i set static networking instead of dhcp and set the eth0 ip and netmask but i forget to add the getway, so the connection is lost and i can't connect to the server any more.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Call your ISP.  There is really nothing we can do to help you if you have broken networking on your server.

Comment: My kingdom for a serial console, or IP-KVM

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the configuration files, or just change the current config? If the latter than you could just reboot the VPS using what-ever interface your provider gives for such things.

If you are hosting with someone like linode which allows you to create more than one server within your account then you could try create a simple rescue server (linode have a small image especially for this), connect this to the virtual disk(s) of the disconnected VM and fix the configuration from there.

Failing the above, you will just have to contact your host for support, and ask them to reset/correct the network configuration for you. Depending on your host there may be a charge for this.

Comment: thanks am really using Linode, and i reboot into "rescue mode" then accessed via "Ajax Console", to my server and correct the error and everything is fine know.

Answer (score 1):

thanks am really using Linode, and i reboot into "rescue mode" then accessed via "Ajax Console", to my server and fixed the error and everything is fine now.